# DVD laser on metals

Tags: heat, laser, laser-diode, metal

What metals can be heated using the  laser diode from a DVD?

I tried on plastic and wood and they warmed, but I need some metals that can heat up to at least 20°C.

How much optical power can the laser produce?

Comment: Not many. Metals tend to be very reflective.

Comment: depends on the size of the metal object ... a piece of metal smaller than a pinhead may heat to the required temperature

Comment: How much metal matters. A LOT.

Answer (score 2):

DVD lasers output 100~250mW for pulses, 50~125mW for continuous emission.

Plastic or wood have much smaller heat capacity than metal. This means their temperature rise is higher than that of metal with same amount of laser light energy.

Let's assume that you want to heat a 100g aluminium disk.

$$ C_{ps} = 0.89 \frac{J}{g} {^\circ}C $$

To heat it by 10°C,
$$ Q = C_{ps} \times 100g \times 10{^\circ}C = 890J $$

Assuming 100mW is sent to the aluminium via the laser light energy:

$$ t = \frac{890J}{100mW} = 8900s $$

Thus, you'll need the laser beam to shine for more than 2 hours continuously. Meanwhile, you must keep the aluminium disk thermally insulated to prevent loss of accumulated heat.

Does this seem possible?

Comment: Even worse aluminium reflects around 85% of the incident light, so it would take 5-6 times longer :) Other polished metal surfaces are not much better. If you can, make the surface rough and black.